# Filter by JSON object by keys

Tags: javascript, filter

I am trying to filter this JSON object by the keys:

The data looks like this

```
key1: value1
key2: value2
key3: value3
key4: value4
key5: value5
key6: value6
key7: value7
key8: value8
key9: value9
```

Currently what I am doing right now is renaming the keys to fit that strucure and then try to filter it out.

```
    var reassaignedKeys;

    props.data.map((entries, valuesIndex) => {
      reassaignedKeys =  Object.assign({}, {Owner: entries[0], ApplicationId: entries[1], ApplicationName: entries[2], Status: entries[3], DeploymentStatus: entries[4], Classification: entries[5], PersonalBindle: entries[6], PerviouslyCertified: entries[7], Goal: entries[8]})
  
    })
    console.log(reassaignedKeys)
```

This code above is what I am using to rename the keys, I am now confused on how to filter out the key and value using the key.

I know I can use

```
Object.keys.filter
```

But I am not getting the results I want is it keeps returning the same array back to me

Comment: `The data looks like this` that's not JSON - it's not even clear what the actual structure is - there's also no indication what `props.data` and `reassaignedKeys` will only be the value of the last iteration of that `.map`

Comment: Please add any relevant JavaScript code to your question as a [mcve]. You can use the snippet tool `[<>]` in the question edit toolbar to help you. You should also add in an example of the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make something like this :

```
const filteredJson = Object.entries(originalJson).reduce((acc,[key,value])=>{
  const isValidKey = key !== 'A' // for exemple
  if(!isValidKey) return acc
  return {
         ...acc,
        [key]:value}
},{})
```

You can also use lodash [pickBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#pickBy) or [omitBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#omitBy) functions

Answer (score 0):

I don’t quite understand what you wan't, but if you want get keys or key-values pairs, and assuming that your `JSON` is correct
like this.

```
[{"key1":"value1"},
{"key2":"value2"},
{"key3":"value3"},
{"key4":"value4"},
{"key5":"value5"},
{"key6":"value6"},
{"key7":"value7"},
{"key8":"value8"},
{"key9":"value9"}]
```

Than you can do `JSON.parse` to parse your `JSON` to `JS` object, and use

> To get keys

```
Object.keys(converted_obj_from_json);
```

> To get key-value pairs

```
Object.entries(converted_obj_from_json);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just get your entries with

```
const entries = data.flatMap(Object.values);
```

```js
const data = [{"key1":"value1"},
{"key2":"value2"},
{"key3":"value3"},
{"key4":"value4"},
{"key5":"value5"},
{"key6":"value6"},
{"key7":"value7"},
{"key8":"value8"},
{"key9":"value9"}];

const entries = data.flatMap(Object.values);

const reassaignedKeys =  Object.assign({}, {Owner: entries[0], ApplicationId: entries[1], ApplicationName: entries[2], Status: entries[3], DeploymentStatus: entries[4], Classification: entries[5], PersonalBindle: entries[6], PerviouslyCertified: entries[7], Goal: entries[8]});

console.log(reassaignedKeys)
```